# CMake Script throwings Errors While Trying to Build ZXing (Native) for Android

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, zxing

I am trying to build ZXing from its [C++ source code](https://github.com/glassechidna/zxing-cpp) in Android Studio. But CMake is throwing a lot of errors, while I am not having much experience with NDK development, and errors are not descriptive enough to understand, can't figure out whats going wrong here. Right now, I am facing the following issue;

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:90 (add_executable):
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:91 (add_executable):
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:92 (target_link_libraries):
```

I tried to read through [CMake docs](https://cmake.org/examples/) to understand the syntax of commands, they seems fine in CMakeLists.txt (listed below).

Can somebody experienced with these native stuff please shed some light.

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(zxing)

option(BUILD_TESTING "Enable generation of test targets" OFF)

set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/local/lib ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH})
set(OpenCV_DIR C:/opencv-3.4.3-android-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni)
# set(Iconv_DIR C:/Users/bcs/Downloads/libiconv-1.9.2-1-bin)


# Check for polluted source tree.
if(EXISTS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeCache.txt OR
    EXISTS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeFiles)
    message(FATAL_ERROR
        "Source directory is polluted:"
        "\n  * remove CMakeCache.txt"
        "\n  * remove CMakeFiles directory")
endif()

# Suppress in-source builds.
if(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} STREQUAL ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
    message(FATAL_ERROR
        "CMake generation is not allowed within the source directory:"
        "\n  * mkdir build"
        "\n  * cd build"
        "\n  * Unix-like: cmake -G \"Unix Makefiles\" .."
        "\n  * Windows: cmake -G \"Visual Studio 10\" ..")
endif()

# Adjust CMake's module path.
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/FindModules)

# Suppress MSVC CRT warnings.
if(MSVC)
    add_definitions(-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
    add_definitions(/Za)
    add_definitions(/MP) # multi-core builds
endif()

include(source_files.cmake)

if(WIN32)
    include_directories(core/lib/win32)
    set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX -debug)
endif()

# OpenCV classes
find_package(OpenCV)
if(OpenCV_FOUND)
    list(APPEND LIBZXING_FILES
        opencv/src/zxing/MatSource.cpp
        opencv/src/zxing/MatSource.h
    )

    include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    include_directories(opencv/src)
endif()

include_directories(core/src)
add_library(libzxing ${LIBZXING_FILES})
set_target_properties(libzxing PROPERTIES PREFIX "")

find_package(Iconv)
if(ICONV_FOUND)
    include_directories(${ICONV_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(libzxing ${ICONV_LIBRARIES})
 else()
   add_definitions(-DNO_ICONV=1)
 endif()
    add_definitions(-DNO_ICONV=1)

# Add OpenCV cli executable
if(OpenCV_FOUND)
    file(GLOB_RECURSE OPENCV_ZXING_FILES
        "./opencv-cli/src/*.cpp"
        "./opencv-cli/src/*.h"
    )
    # add_executable(zxing-cv ${OPENCV_ZXING_FILES})
    add_executable(zxing-cv "./opencv-cli/src/*.cpp")
    target_link_libraries(zxing-cv libzxing ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
endif()

# Add cli executable.
file(GLOB_RECURSE ZXING_FILES
    "./cli/src/*.cpp"
    "./cli/src/*.h"
)

 add_executable(zxing ${ZXING_FILES})
 add_executable(zxing-cv "./opencv-cli/src/*.cpp")
 target_link_libraries(zxing libzxing)

install(TARGETS zxing libzxing EXPORT zxing-targets
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    INCLUDES DESTINATION include
)

install(EXPORT zxing-targets DESTINATION lib/zxing/cmake NAMESPACE zxing::)

install(
    DIRECTORY core/src/zxing/
    DESTINATION include/zxing
    FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
)

if(OpenCV_FOUND)
    install(
        DIRECTORY opencv/src/zxing/
        DESTINATION include/zxing
        FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
    )
endif()

configure_file(cmake/zxing-config.cmake.in zxing-config.cmake @ONLY)
install(FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/zxing-config.cmake DESTINATION lib/zxing/cmake)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
    # Add testrunner executable.
    find_package(CPPUNIT)
    if(CPPUNIT_FOUND)
        file(GLOB_RECURSE TESTRUNNER_FILES
            "./core/tests/src/*.cpp"
            "./core/tests/src/*.h"
        )
        add_executable(testrunner ${TESTRUNNER_FILES})
        include_directories(${CPPUNIT_INCLUDE_DIR})
        target_link_libraries(testrunner libzxing  ${CPPUNIT_LIBRARIES})
    endif()
endif()
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that using wildcards directly with `add_executable` (i.e. `"./opencv-cli/src/*.cpp"`) is supported. I thought you had to use `GLOB` for that. The problem with the first `add_executable` is probably due to some issue with `ZXING_FILES`, e.g. it being empty because you specified the wrong file path or something. `target_link_libraries` would then fail as a result of `add_executable` failing.

Comment: `ZXING_FILES` is defined in an included file (source_files.cmake), different source file paths are assigned to it, and I checked all those files, they all exists at the specified location. I will try with GLOB.

Comment: Rather than checking if the files are where you think CMake is looking for them, I'd suggest printing the contents of `ZXING_FILES` to see what it contains. By the way, you're trying to `add_executable(zxing-cv` twice; once conditionally and then once unconditionally.

Comment: Great, trying to print the contents now :) Regarding the twice entry, I am using this file as its from the the repo, not having much knowledge about CMake (or native development)

Comment: Its printing a [list of filenames](https://pastebin.com/3yvA5BiG) `(I used MESSAGE( STATUS "LIBZXING_FILES is: " ${LIBZXING_FILES} ) to print)`, but not all files there, and end of the printed string also showing the text `Warnning at CMakeLists.txt:68 (find_package):`. Also, printed the var `OPENCV_ZXING_FILES`, which is coming empty. Don't know what to assign to it.

Comment: `LIBZXING_FILES` and `ZXING_FILES` are two different variables.

Answer (score 1):

#### You could switch to nu-book/zxing-cpp

There has been quite some confusion around the various ports of ZXing to C++. Since recently, [`nu-book/zxing-cpp`](https://github.com/nu-book/zxing-cpp) is considered something like the "official" ZXing C++ port, following [this discussion](https://github.com/nu-book/zxing-cpp/issues/44).

According to my own estimation, that is the most active and most advanced of the current ports. It differs from the port [glassechidna/zxing-cpp](https://github.com/glassechidna/zxing-cpp) that you tried to use by being a complete re-implementation in C++, not a direct 1:1 port from the original ZXing Java API to C++. That should make the names etc. "nicer" in a C++ environment.

#### Building it

I had no major issues building nu-book/zxing-cpp and using it in an application (though I have yet to try it for Android). I did not use Android Studio to build it though, but just the console, as follows:

```
cd /path/to/zxing-cpp/sources && mkdir build && cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/zxing-cpp/sources/export
make
make install
```

After that, you can use it in a CMake based project that is configured with `cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/path/to/zxing-cpp/sources/export/lib/cmake/ZXing` and has this in its `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(ZXing REQUIRED)
add_executable( ... )
target_link_libraries(minimal-zxing-demo ZXing::ZXing)
```